# Is it possible to trigger a google script externally?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace-for-business

> **Backstory**:  We use Google Sheets via Gsuite and have several users. I'm using the admin account and creating some parsing scripts that load a CSV, extract processed data and place them into the google sheet that hosts the script.  Once a month, a different user will upload the csv using a naming convention and I will open the sheet (the script is triggered via an onOpen trigger) to make the script run and everything works fine, so this part is done and working well.

**The Goal**: What I'd like to do is allow the user uploading the CSV (our office manager) to somehow trigger this script without being logged in as me.  We have zapier at our disposal if that helps, but I'd rather avoid a significant change to the script to get this rolling for such a small, but nice-to-have payoff.

**The Question**: Is there a path of least resistance to trigger this script via some other user with access to the sheet that doesn't involve a lot of additional steps from them, such as an api call from somewhere, google form or anything that could essentially be connected to a button press by the other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "path of least resistance" is very likely to publish a Google Apps Script web app set it up to be ran as you that call "the script". For details see the [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) on the official Google Apps Script site.
.